# How can I manually remove a dead OCS 2007 R2 Monitoring server?

Tags: wmi, lync, ms-office-communicator

At the moment, I'm trying to get what is effectively a cut down version of our production OCS 2007 R2 environment working in a segregated lab. For a variety of different reasons, this initially consisted of a verbatim copy of our OCS 2007 R2 Active Directory forest - however for reasons of budget, we cannot replicate all of the actual servers involved in the production environment, so I'm left with an OCS installation that thinks there are many more servers in it than are really present.

For the most part I've managed to force deactivation of these servers using lcscmd, and a bit of pruning with ADSIEdit in Active Directory to take care of the leftovers.

However the Monitoring server just won't vanish from the OCS admin tool. I *think* I've tracked this down to an WMI entry (an instance of MSFT_SIPMonitoringServerSetting in root\cimv2) - but I'm stumped as to how to remove this. WBEMTest won't let me delete the offending instance and keeps reporting "Provider is not capable". Surely there must be *some* way to get rid of this?

The eventual goal is to get a Lync install working here, but the import of the OCS infrastructure will keep failing unless what I have physically present logically matches the configuration data.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Further Info : So it turns out I really wasn't super familiar with WMI before. Now having read around it a bit more, it seems it can (rarely) be used as a repository in its own right - but more often is just a "view" into other repositories. OCS seems to store data accessible via WMI in either the rtcconfig database or in Active Directory. The Monitor server info isn't in rtcconfig, so logically must be in AD somewhere. Anyone know how to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I went the brute force and ignorance approach, and just deleted about 110 orphaned AD entries from the 'RTC Service' section of Active Directory.

Somewhere in there I nailed the right one - but no idea which it was.

This is, therefore, a rather crappy answer - but the best I can offer.